# Component selector in variable - Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, ng-bootstrap

I have written my own table module. Calling it in HTML code looks like this:

```
<my-table [data]="variableWithArr"></my-table>
```

Now, pretty nice table is being displayed. Cool. But what if I want to have a progress bar in some column of table? I thought that I could put a HTML code with component selector as value, for example bootstrap progressBar, like this:

```
for(let record of variableWithArr) {
    record[0] = '<ngb-progressbar type="danger" [value]="100"></ngb-progressbar>';
}
```

Unfortunatelly, Angular displays only a HTML code but dooes not interpret it as component selector, so I receive something like that in DOM:

```
<td><ngb-progressbar type="danger" [value]="100"></ngb-progressbar></td>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not how Angular works - you can't insert arbitrary HTML (`innerHTML` or otherwise) and expect that directives will be picked up & applied. Making Angular work this way would require shipping entire compiler to a browser and would defeat the whole purpose of all the great optimizations that can be done with the ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation.

tl;dr; nope, you can't do this and this has nothing to do with the ng-bootstrap project, but rather with design decisions behind Angular.

Comment: So in that case, there is pointless to make tables which calling is like main?

Comment: Yeh, I think that you need to play with different approaches to your table widget...

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#content-security) you need to use the property [innerHTML], but to be clear only use it when you trust the code!!

So should be something like this:

```
<td [innerHTML]="record"></td>
```

Comment: I am doing this already but I Angular do not interpret component selector, just prints it.